# "auf etwas hin"

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet die Kombination "auf etwas hin" in den folgenden Beispielen:

> auf einen massiven Protest hin
>
> einen Aufsatz auf Fehler hin prüfen
>
> auf behördliche Mahnung hin
>
> auf etwas hinarbeiten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deine vier Beispiele decken drei verschiedene Bedeutungen ab, die kaum etwas miteinander zu tun haben:

### auf ein Ziel hinarbeiten

»Auf etwas hinarbeiten« bedeutet: Arbeiten um das genante Ziel zu erreichen. Das Ziel ist ein Ereignis, das in der Zukunft liegt, und dessen Erreichung möglich, aber nicht sicher ist.

> Klaus arbeitet auf eine Beförderung zum Abteilungsleiter hin.

Das bedeutet: Klaus unternimmt Maßnahmen, mit dem ausdrücklichen Ziel, dadurch die Chancen auf eine Beförderung zu erhöhen.

Das Wort »hin« ist hier aber kein eigenständiges Wort, sondern ein Teil des trennbaren Verbs »hinarbeiten«.

---

### etwas auf einen Anlass hin tun

> Die Geschäftsführung zog ihre Pläne, auf massive Proteste der Belegschaft hin, wieder zurück.

Das bedeutet, dass die massiven Proteste der Belegschaft (also ein Ereignis, das in der Vergangenheit stattgefunden hat) die Ursache für das Zurückziehen der Pläne sind. Hier liegt also eine Ursache-Wirkung-Beziehung vor.

> *(A zu B):* Auf deinen Vorschlag hin habe ich gestern Abend die Möbel umgestellt. Gefällt es dir so besser?

Das bedeutet: B hat irgendwann in der Vergangenheit einen Vorschlag gemacht, der eine Veränderung der Position der Möbel im Zimmer zum Inhalt hatte. A hat aufgrund dieses Vorschlages nun tatsächlich die Möbel anders arrangiert und bittet nun B um eine Rückmeldung.

> Gerald S. musste seinen Würstelstand auf behördliche Anordnung hin schließen.

Eine Behörde hat eine Anordnung erlassen, Gerald S. hat diese Anordnung befolgt.

---

### etwas auf etwas anderes hin prüfen/untersuchen

> *(Chef zu seinem Team):* Könnt ihr euren Ansatz bitte nochmal auf Fehler hin prüfen? Ich will sicher sein, dass das auch wirklich funktioniert.

Das Team hat seinem Chef einen Ansatz vorgestellt, der Chef will aber mehr Sicherheit, und bittet sein Team noch einmal zu überprüfen, ob der Ansatz Fehler enthält.

> Der Arzt hat das Blut des Unfalllenkers auf Drogen hin untersucht.

Das bedeutet: Der Arzt hat eine Blutprobe analysiert, mit dem Ziel, darin eventuell vorhandene Drogen nachzuweisen.